# Full examples of using pySerial package

Tags: python, modem, pyserial

Can someone please show me a full python sample code that uses **pyserial**, i have the package and am wondering how to send the AT commands and read them back!

Answer (score 101):

Blog post [Serial RS232 connections in Python](https://web.archive.org/web/20230724164107/https://www.varesano.net/serial-rs232-connections-in-python/)

```
import time
import serial

# configure the serial connections (the parameters differs on the device you are connecting to)
ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyUSB1',
    baudrate=9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_ODD,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO,
    bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS
)

ser.isOpen()

print 'Enter your commands below.\r\nInsert "exit" to leave the application.'

input=1
while 1 :
    # get keyboard input
    input = raw_input(">> ")
        # Python 3 users
        # input = input(">> ")
    if input == 'exit':
        ser.close()
        exit()
    else:
        # send the character to the device
        # (note that I happend a \r\n carriage return and line feed to the characters - this is requested by my device)
        ser.write(input + '\r\n')
        out = ''
        # let's wait one second before reading output (let's give device time to answer)
        time.sleep(1)
        while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
            out += ser.read(1)
            
        if out != '':
            print ">>" + out
```

Comment: I received an error `serial.serialutil.SerialException: Port is already open` when running this code. I'm not certain on this but I believe the serial port is automatically opened when it is explicitly defined as you have done with `ser`. After commenting out the `ser.open()` line it worked.

Comment: This comment is the saviour.

Comment: @user3817250: Alternatively just make an if-case around the `ser.open()`

Comment: btw, having a ser.isopen() all by itself doesn't have any meaning.  You can use isopen(r) in a conditional to check to see if it is already open, of course, before you try to open it yourself..  If so, it may indicate your program is already running elsewhere.  Then use some Python Fu to kill the other process and then retry the open.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178705/python-pyserial-how-to-know-if-a-port-is-already-open

Comment: Hi, great code! I have a question, how would you change if you use python 3 instead?

Answer (score 50):

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial(0)  # open first serial port
print ser.portstr       # check which port was really used
ser.write("hello")      # write a string
ser.close()             # close port
```

use https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/ for more examples

Answer (score 29):

http://web.archive.org/web/20131107050923/http://www.roman10.net/serial-port-communication-in-python/comment-page-1/

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import serial, time
#initialization and open the port

#possible timeout values:
#    1. None: wait forever, block call
#    2. 0: non-blocking mode, return immediately
#    3. x, x is bigger than 0, float allowed, timeout block call

ser = serial.Serial()
#ser.port = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
ser.port = "/dev/ttyUSB7"
#ser.port = "/dev/ttyS2"
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS #number of bits per bytes
ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE #set parity check: no parity
ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE #number of stop bits
#ser.timeout = None          #block read
ser.timeout = 1            #non-block read
#ser.timeout = 2              #timeout block read
ser.xonxoff = False     #disable software flow control
ser.rtscts = False     #disable hardware (RTS/CTS) flow control
ser.dsrdtr = False       #disable hardware (DSR/DTR) flow control
ser.writeTimeout = 2     #timeout for write

try: 
    ser.open()
except Exception, e:
    print "error open serial port: " + str(e)
    exit()

if ser.isOpen():

    try:
        ser.flushInput() #flush input buffer, discarding all its contents
        ser.flushOutput()#flush output buffer, aborting current output 
                 #and discard all that is in buffer

        #write data
        ser.write("AT+CSQ")
        print("write data: AT+CSQ")

       time.sleep(0.5)  #give the serial port sometime to receive the data

       numOfLines = 0

       while True:
          response = ser.readline()
          print("read data: " + response)

        numOfLines = numOfLines + 1

        if (numOfLines >= 5):
            break

        ser.close()
    except Exception, e1:
        print "error communicating...: " + str(e1)

else:
    print "cannot open serial port "
```

Answer (score 2):

I have not used pyserial but based on the API documentation at https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html it seems like a very nice interface.  It might be worth double-checking the specification for AT commands of the device/radio/whatever you are dealing with.

Specifically, some require some period of silence before and/or after the AT command for it to enter into command mode.  I have encountered some which do not like reads of the response without some delay first.