# Python : How to know serial port device events like keybord events

Tags: python, python-2.7, serial-port, pyserial

Hi i am new to python i am able to connect to the serial port device & want to know any changes are happened in the device (i want catch the event if any button is press in the device) How can i do this.With The help of pyHook in python i am able to find the keyboard events and mouse events with calling the functions "OnKeyboardEvent" & "OnMouseEvent" how to catch the any serial port device events.Is there any thing in python OnSerailportdeviceEvent function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in library for using serial ports in Python, you need to use the [PySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) library, and then, you just read data from the serial port line by line and see if that line contains data; if it does it means that something changed on your serial device (a button press, for example).

Here's a few links that will help you using that library :

[Official PySerial documentation](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/shortintro.html)

[Blog post that may be useful to you](http://www.varesano.net/blog/fabio/serial%20rs232%20connections%20python)

[Question on StackOverflow about PySerial with some helpful answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676172/full-examples-of-using-pyserial-package).

Comment: I am able do with reading reading line by line data continuously but i don't want to go with this continuous process, i want to catch OnchangeEvent, is it possible to get the data only when button is pressed

Comment: I don't think that is possible with a serial port.