# How to Detect event generated by USB device into raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, usb, barcode-scanner

Hello geniuses i want to only detect the event generated by a usb device attached to it like barcode scanner.Now want that a barcode scanner is plugged in to a usb port of a raspberry pi.now when it scan then how can my rpi detect that a usb device has generated a event.

Comment: Hi @lalit-kushwah , welcome to SO or sort of ... What have you done so far ... ? Please show us your steps

Comment: I think you are looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19152327/5012922)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully [PyUSB](https://walac.github.io/pyusb/) works, and in that case you can follow [this guide](http://martinsant.net/?page_id=983)
If for whatever reason that doesn't work, you could open the `/dev/tty` device direclty with a standard:

```
with open('/dev/tty4', 'rb') as fh:
    for event in fh.read(8)
```

Note that `/dev/tty` is just a out-of-the-hat example, your device might end up somewhere else. Check `dmsg` and `lsusb` to determine where your device got mounted, if at all mounted or discovered. You might need specific drivers for your scanner.