# No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyUSB0'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am trying to interface a Raspberry Pi with a USB RFID card reader using a Python script. For the record, my code is as follows:

```
import serial, time, sys
import sqlite3 as lite

reader = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
ser = serial.Serial(reader, timeout=1)
print("Connected to RFID reader on:", reader)

try:
    while True:
        thetime = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %a %H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
        ser.flushInput() # flush any extra data from the serial port
        rfid_data = ser.readline().strip()

        if len(rfid_data) > 0:
            rfid_data = rfid_data[1:11]
            print("Card scanned", rfid_data)


        else:
            print("Card not found")

except:
    print("Unexpected error")

finally:
    ser.close()
```

I'm actually receiving more than one error at the moment. Instead of trying my best to explain it in my own words, I am sure that the following snippet would be more useful to most of you.

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 275, in open
>     self.fd = os.open(self.portstr, os.O_RDWR|os.O_NOCTTY|os.O_NONBLOCK)
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyUSB0'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/pi/Desktop/Alex Panagis/rfidtestfinal.py", line 5, in <module>
>     ser = serial.Serial(reader, timeout=1)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 261, in __init__
>     self.open()
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 278, in open
>     raise SerialException("could not open port %s: %s" % (self._port, msg))
> serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyUSB0'
> ```

Any help in resolving this issue is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Possible duplicate [how-to-detect-event-generated-by-usb-device-into-raspberry-pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34656789/how-to-detect-event-generated-by-usb-device-into-raspberry-pi)

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I seem to have the same problem.