# Is there a way to avoid polling when looking for serial port changes in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, serial-port, pyserial

Currently I am using [*pySerial*](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial) and its `list_ports.comports()` function to poll for changes of the currently available serial ports of devices with a certain vid/pid. I'd like to know if there is a way to avoid polling and get notified of a port change instead?

Comment: It might be pretty heavy but maybe delve into the [```asyncio```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html#module-asyncio) module - no experience myself with it but skimming over it looks like it can solve many *problems*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have to deal with some of C/C++ code, integrated with Python: https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html. I'm afraid, such low-level functions are almost impossible in hi-level programming language like Python.
Also look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19152327/1828296