# pySerial write() won't take my string

Tags: python, pyserial

Using Python 3.3 and pySerial for serial communications.

I'm trying to write a command to my COM PORT but the write method won't take my string. (Most of the code is from here [Full examples of using pySerial package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676172/full-examples-of-using-pyserial-package)

What's going on?

```
import time
import serial


ser = serial.Serial(
    port='\\\\.\\COM4',
    baudrate=115200,
    parity=serial.PARITY_ODD,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
)
if ser.isOpen():
    ser.close()
ser.open()
ser.isOpen()

ser.write("%01#RDD0010000107**\r")
out = ''
# let's wait one second before reading output (let's give device time to answer)
time.sleep(1)
while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
    out += ser.read(40)

if out != '':
    print(">>" + out)


ser.close()
```

Error is at ser.write("%01#RDD0010000107**\r") where it gets 
Traceback is like this
data = to_bytes(data)
b.append(item)
TypeError: an integer is required.

Comment: Probably because serial expects a bytearray and not a string in python3. Perhaps the following can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585435/best-way-to-convert-string-to-bytes-in-python-3

Comment: adding .encode() after my string fixed my problem! (I also stripped some of the unnecessary parts out). Thanks!

Comment: @Garvin If the problem is solved, could you please write an answer yourself and mark the question as answered? Thanks!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It turns out that the string needed to be turned into a bytearray and to do this I editted the code to

```
ser.write("%01#RDD0010000107**\r".encode())
```

This solved the problem

Answer (score 10):

You have found the root cause. Alternately do like this:

```
ser.write(bytes(b'your_commands'))
```

Comment: `b'your_commands'` is already bytes, see [b-prefixed string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal) - why should we convert it again using `bytes()`?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same "TypeError:  an integer is required" error message when attempting to write.
Thanks, the .encode() solved it for me.
I'm running python 3.4 on a Dell D530 running 32 bit Windows XP Pro.

I'm omitting the com port settings here:

```
>>>import serial

>>>ser = serial.Serial(5)

>>>ser.close()

>>>ser.open()

>>>ser.write("1".encode())

1

>>>
```