# Serial readline method in python 3.x

Tags: python, arduino, sensors, pyserial

[pySerial write() won't take my string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22275079/pyserial-write-wont-take-my-string)

In that post, coders explained how to use the

> ser.write()

method.

I am still wondering how to use the

> readline()

method in python3.x as I want to recieve a float, and compare it in my python 3.x code. I know how to use the readline() in python 2.7. But I am not able to get it working in 3.x.

```
import serial
import time

ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
while 1:
    ans = ser.readline()
    print(ans)
    if ans > 25.50:
        print('its getting hot in  here')
    else:
        print('Everything is fine')
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that occurs to me is that `ans` will be a string variable after `readline()`.  You can't compare a string to a floating-point variable without some conversion.  So:

```
if ans > 25.50:
```

will not work because `ans` is a string.  Instead, you need something like:

```
float_ans = float(ans)
if float_ans > 25.50:
# etc...
```