# Raspberry pi mb+ UART 8bit message

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, uart

I want to send a message from Rpi to Atmega328 via UART and there must be only 8 bit message (address, address, direction, number of steps [5 bits]).

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import serial
import time,sys


var=0b11110000
SERIAL_PORT = "/dev/ttyS0"
ser=serial.Serial(SERIAL_PORT,baudrate=9600,parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)
time.sleep(1)
print("Sending")
ser.write(var)
ser.close()
```

But i got this

```
Sending
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "UART_2.py", line 11, in <module>
ser.write(var)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 558, in write
return len(data)
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

What should I do to send it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you should give a byte array to `ser.write` instead of sending a single value. Try using `var=[0b11110000]` which has a length, that the integer `0b11110000` doesn't have.
If you can encode your byte as a string, you can also find more answers at [pySerial write() won't take my string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22275079/pyserial-write-wont-take-my-string)