# Read GPS data from com port

Tags: python, gps

I am trying to read a GPS from a  com port. I really have no idea what that means, but I have a Bu-535 GPS receiver and the driver is properly installed and a GPSinfo.exe is installed (the GPS receiver doesn't produce sentences, but that's another story). The GPSinfo.exe obviously knows how to read the data from the com port (using the driver or something).

So, I need to know how to use **Python** to connect to the GPS receiver and then read the string of binary info that it is producing so that I can throw it into a database and interpret it later.

Based on your knowledge, can you tell me what the Python library is called (I read -- I think -- that a GPS library is built in but couldn't find it... is there a built in one to read binary data from GPS?) and also how to I get the data in the first place (i.e. how do I connect to the com port. If you  know how to do this in Java, that would also be helpful so that I can get my bearings, but I would prefer Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [pyserial](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial) If you wish to read data from COM Ports.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/676240/3244627) SO Answer for more info on how to use pyserial.

Comment: Does it work with gpsfeed+? A virtual serial port data generator.