# External vs internal declaration of QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I have currently some problems with the `QSerialPort`: When I am using the function from an example which looks like

```
QKeyEvent *e;
emit getData(e->text().toLocal8Bit());
connect(console, SIGNAL(getData(QByteArray)), this, SLOT(writeData(QByteArray)));
void MainWindow::writeData(const QByteArray &data)
{
    qDebug() << "Data is to write: " << data;
    serial->write(data);
}
```

then the receiving device can work with the data. But when I change the function `writeData()` to

```
void MainWindow::writeData(const QByteArray &data)
{
    QString a = "Q";
    QByteArray b = a.toLocal8Bit();
    serial->write(b);
}
```

the receiving device can not work with the received data. Where is the difference between those two approaches?
Update: I found out that apparently the data is only usefully transferred if I press `Enter` after typing the letters. Somehow the `'\n'` gets lost in the conversion from `QString` to `QByteArray`. How can I keep it?

Comment: What does `serial->write(b)` return?

Comment: May calling ``flush()`` will help, if you are not receving data correctly. Also did you try calling original function supplying the same data? I doubt getData() will only return 'Q'.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: It returns the number of bytes, in the first case `3`, in the second `1`

Comment: Added an update to the question.

Comment: @arc_lupus, if it doesn't return `-1`, the data _has_ actually been written. What exactly do you mean by "the receiving device can not work with the received data"?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: In the first case I get an answer, in the second I don't, even if I transmit a `Q` both times.

Comment: `QString a = "Q\x00D"`

Comment: @Pim: That was the solution, thanks! If you create an answer based on that I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add an enter to your Qstring like this

`QString a = "Q\x00D";`

Answer (score 0):

In the example you have given, there is no "\n" in the QString! It is not getting lost, it is not there in the first place.

If a newline is necessary, then construct the String as `QString a = "Q\n"`.

You can also construct the QByteArray directly from a character array rather than going through a char array -> QString -> QByteArrray conversion sequence, like so:

```
QByteArray b("Q\n");
```

EDIT: I realized that your contrived example where you are just sending the letter "Q" is probably a debug attempt, not your real code. In reality, you're getting data in as a QByteArray from some other signal that is emitting a QByteArray. That QByteArray that you are receiving must not include the newline character in it. If you are reading from a file or user input, then that is normal. Most readline-like functions strip off the trailing newline. If it is always necessary to have a newline, you can simply do something like this in your WriteData method:

```
void MainWindow::writeData(const QByteArray &data)
{
    serial->write(data);
    serial->write("\n");
}
```

If sometimes the passed-in QByteArray has a newline at the end and sometimes not, and your receiving device cannot handle redundant newlines, then you'd need to check whether data ends with a newline and only write the "\n" if it does not.

Answer (score 0):

what if you make the `QByteArray` like this

```
QByteArray b(&a);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Perhaps my answer should have had more details as to why I think it is the answer. I assume you mean that when you say this doesn't provide an answer. But I was neither trying to criticize the question nor request a clarification.