# win32.SetCommState with Pyserial in win10

Tags: python, windows-10, pyserial

Until recently I was happily using win7 + pythonX and pyserial. 
Lately I upgraded to win10, now I have a problem running some python serial code which I had working on win7.

However I can even run the simple example from: [Full examples of using pySerial package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676172/full-examples-of-using-pyserial-package)

What I get is the same error, on all pyserial related codes:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File ".\t.py", line 10, in 
>       bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS
>     File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 31, in **init**
>       super(Serial, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 240, in **init**
>       self.open()
>     File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 78, in open
>       self._reconfigure_port()
>     File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 222, in _reconfigure_port
>       'Original message: {!r}'.format(ctypes.WinError()))
>   serial.serialutil.SerialException: Cannot configure port, something went wrong. Original message: OSError(22, 'The parameter is incorrect.', None, 87)

however I found out that the reason for this is the exception raised by a call "win32.SetCommState(self._port_handle, ctypes.byref(comDCB)):" from serialwin32.py

This call returns 0, indicating something is wrong, but when i comment it out then I can get the serial communication working again, anyone else experienced this ? any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: I have the exact same issue.  It's a bummer you didn't get any answers.  I wish the error message said which parameter was incorrect.