# My RAMPS1.4 doesn't work when controlled by RPI5 via Python3

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyserial, g-code, 3d-printing

When I use my Windows device to control ramps1.4 (mounted on mega Arduino) via Python3, by g code like this:

```
import serial
import time

myPort = serial.Serial('COM7', 250000, parity='N')
time.sleep(1)

myPort.write('M302 S0\n'.encode())
myPort.write('G1 Z-50 F1000000\n'.encode())
myPort.write('M84\n'.encode())
```

everything is good and my step motors work. Next, when I connect this board to my Raspberry Pi5 device and change the `myPort` code to `myPort = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 250000, parity='N')` connection is established and RAMPS1.4 light flashing to tell us that port is connected but my g code does not work and step motors remain motionless (without any error). First I thought that's issue relates to the Baud rate. So, to solve this problem I tried to change the baud rate in Raspberry Pi 5 via this code `stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 115200` and checked it again, but that did not work either. Also, I tried any other standard baud rate and failed at all of them.
I tried this solution too but doesn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59966088/23310292  /  https://stackoverflow.com/a/76734740/23310292 .
Next, I thought maybe this console was inactive, so I tried this code `sudo systemctl enable getty@ttyACM0.service`, and not work either.
And now, I don't know how to solve it.